# SVG animate begin event inside HTML div

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to embed an animated svg as follows inside a html document (this is a reduced minimal example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Circle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="circle">
        <img src="circle1.svg" width="auto" height="100%" alt="Image One" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="5000" height="1000" border="3px solid #eee" display="block" margin="1em auto" xml:space="preserve">
        <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />
        <animate 
                         xlink:href="#orange-circle"
                         attributeName="r"
                         from="30"
                         to="450" 
                         dur="1s"
                         begin="click"
                         fill="freeze" />
</svg>
```

The SVG animation works for me as a standalone and also it works in the html if I remove the `<div ...></div>` tags.

But the animation does not start if I use the above. Does the SVG not receive the click event and how can I fix this?

Note that I do not want to replace the SVG animation with a javascript equivalent because I cannot really control the generation of the SVG, and I would also prefer not to inline the SVG.

Comment: Thanks. The `<object>` tag does it for me. Seems that the fact that the problem occurred when I added the `<div>` tag distracted me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of `<img>` elements are not interactive, so they can't process click events. You'd have to use a different container element here e.g. `<object>` or `<iframe>`